# get UNDEFINED in redux data in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

got the data in reducer but can't get in component.
this is my connection code.

```js
  const mapStateToProps =state => {
    return {
      name:state.fbLogin.name
    }
  }
    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
      return bindActionCreators(ActionCreators,dispatch);
    }
  export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Chat);
```

i want to access the name using this.props.name but got "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Check your store, make sure you have a reducer for fbLogin in place, the code seems to be correct, you may want to add default props so you don't get any undefined errors

Comment: all set in reducer perfectly..still can't get

Answer (score -1):

restart your app ..
some time getting data from reducers give undefined after restarting the app
you can see the real data

hope this helps you

Comment: Thank You buddy..it's working now after restart my app.it's working like a charm..thanks